# delay in a loop(gtk+,C)

Tags: gtk

I am doing a project in gtk+,it's a game and I need some objects to enter the window once every 7 seconds,I searched but I couldn't find any relevant command to bring some seconds of delay every time a loop is compiled!Is there any fucntion you can think of?
(I am coding in C)

Answer (score 4):

You want to look at the `g_timeout_add` and `g_timeout_add_seconds` functions https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-The-Main-Event-Loop.html#g-timeout-add-seconds